# Get rid of SourceSafe source control

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

One of my projects was under SourceSafe and I am using VS2008.
Recently I switched to SVN. I removed all SS related files and committed the source files into SVN. Anyway, when I open my solution I'm still getting this inoffensive but annoying message (see picture below):

```
The source control provider associated with this solution could not be found. The projects will be treated as not under source control.

Do you want to permanently remove the source control bindings from the projects?
```

[image]

I answered multiple time Yes and saved all the files, the I closed the solution and reopen it. I always get this message.
Where can I manually remove any binding left there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will need to touch the solution file and each project file in the solution.

**In the .sln file you will see the following section which needs to be removed.**

```
GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution
  ...
EndGlobalSection
```

**In the .csproj file you will see the following lines which need to be removed.**

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Comment: How to touch it? In .sln I have:  GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
  Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
  Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
 EndGlobalSection
In .csproj file I found no SAK occurence

Comment: Remove the contents I mentioned from the .sln and .csproj files.  Instead of `SAK` you might see something different. That is irrelevant. Focus on the xml elements that start with `Scc`.

Comment: I found the issue, finally.
It was inside one of the setup project (.vddproj).

Comment: In VS2015 it is called GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution

Comment: Subversion and VSS are different, but yeah, the procedure should be the same.

Comment: I imported someone else's DLL and started getting this error. Removing those lines in the project of the DLL fixed it - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the solution file - the bindings will be in there. You might want to *check* whether there are any vestiges in the project files as well, but I *think* they're all in the solution.

Comment: @Adi: I can't remember offhand, but it's likely to be pretty obvious. Compare it with a fresh solution with the same number of projects but no source control.

Comment: @Jon Be sure I already did that. I even searched all the project files in my solution for "obvious" text like "source" or "safe" or "control". No luck, though...

Comment: @Adi: Are there any .user files it could be looking through as well?

Comment: @Jon, yes, I have one .user file for each project. I searched inside them but no "suspect" thigs. Anyway, I only get the message once right at the beginning of solution loading. This fact might suggest the issue is inside .sln file.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work... one particular thing is that I don't have SourceSafe installed on my machine. The project was, of course, created on a machine with SS installed, but now I switched to a machine that hasn't. Normally, I would have used the Change Source Control feature, but I can't, as SS is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bkcarroll/archive/2004/03/08/86059.aspx). It is pretty old, but it has sure worked wonders for me in the previous project.

In addition to the above, I would suggest exactly what Jon wrote. Open a new solution, compare and check and remove the unwanted things.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the steps mentioned by @Brian Gideon BUT the problem was still there. I am using visual studio 2012.

I went [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bkcarroll/archive/2004/03/08/86059.aspx) where the method was same with addition of 1-2 steps. Reading onto comments in this blog helped me to realize to change the source control setting in the IDE - Visual Studio 2012.

> Instead of editing the files directly, go to File -> Source Control -> Change source control. Here you can edit the Source Control Binding settings.

In case you are using Visual Studio 2012, [this may work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194961%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Change current source control plug-in to
**Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**